# How can I access values of multiple select list in a form?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a custom form in a custom module with multiple select:

```
$form['sponsors'] = array(
 '#type' => 'select',
 '#options' => $sponsors,
 '#multiple' => TRUE,
 '#size' => 20,
);
```

But I'm stumped how to access the submitted multiple values in the form_submit function. I tried to get the values by looping through the key (one guess was `$form['values']['sponsors'][$key]`) but no luck... anyone can point me in right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: `#` missed in `'size' => 20,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitted data goes into `$form_state['values']` (not `$form['values']`), and in the case of a multiple select/checkbox element you can filter out the selected items like this:

```
function MYMODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $selected = array_filter($form_state['values']['sponsors']);
}
```

As monymirza mentioned you're also missing the `#` symbol at the start of both the `size` and `multiple` keys. I imagine that error is just in your question, not in your actual code, or you'd expect to see more errors.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Clive! And yes my error on #, edited my OP

Answer (score 1):

in case whether the user may select more than one item, `size` value be written like this way:

```
'#size' => $multiple ? min(12, count($options)) : 0,
```

this is how used in (taxonomy.module).